# liquibase-actions status - getting `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: test.log`

Tags: github-actions, liquibase

I'm trying to use the liquibase github status action in my github-actions pipeline:

```
      - name: Status
        id: status
        uses: liquibase-github-actions/status@v4.23.0
        with:
          changeLogFile: 'migration/changelog.xml'
          username: username
          password: password
          url: url
          logLevel: FINE
          logFile: 'test.log'
```

I'm trying to get access to the log file so I can check in another step if there are any changesets to be applied.  However when I run this I get this error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: test.log

java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: test.log
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at liquibase.resource.DirectoryPathHandler.createResource(DirectoryPathHandler.java:52)
    at liquibase.resource.PathHandlerFactory.createResource(PathHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at liquibase.resource.PathHandlerFactory.openResourceOutputStream(PathHandlerFactory.java:95)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.configureLogging(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:721)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.configureLogging(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:689)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.configureScope(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:641)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$execute$3(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:356)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:206)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:182)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.execute(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:354)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.main(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:94)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseLauncher.main(LiquibaseLauncher.java:107)
```

Not sure whats happening, or if there is another way of knowing if a changeset needs to be applied.